# Combine two character vectors

Tags: r, character

I would like to combine two objects (type_1 and type_2) of character class.

type_1

```
[1] "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1"
   [9] "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1" "FSV1_3h_s1"
```

type_2

```
[1] "E14_5_AAACCCAAGAGGCTGT" "E14_5_AAACCCACAAATGATG" "E14_5_AAACCCACAAGGCGTA" "E14_5_AAACCCACATCGGCCA"
   [5] "E14_5_AAACCCAGTTAATGAG" "E14_5_AAACCCATCAACCTTT" "E14_5_AAACCCATCCGCAAAT" "E14_5_AAACCCATCTCCCATG"
   [9] "E14_5_AAACCCATCTTCCACG" "E14_5_AAACGAAAGGAGAGTA" "E14_5_AAACGAAAGGCGAACT" "E14_5_AAACGAAAGTAACGTA"
  [13] "E14_5_AAACGAACAAACTAGA" "E14_5_AAACGAACAATTGAAG" "E14_5_AAACGAACACGACAGA" "E14_5_AAACGAACATAGGCGA"
```

Let's say `type_1` has 16 values and `type_2` has 20. I Want to create a character vector that will contain 36 in total.

Comment: What does *combine* mean???

Comment: lets say type_1 has 16 values ("FSV1_3h_s1") and type_2 20 (E14_5_AAACCCAAGAGGCTGT). Want to create a character that will contain 36 in total

Comment: You can use `c(type_1, type_2)` to concatenate two or more vectors.

Comment: ```c(outer(t1, t2, paste))```